# Background color not changing 'smoothly'. CSS transitions not working

Tags: css, hover, transition

My CSS transitions aren't working. The hover appears but the easing transitions are not working. Please help, thanks!

```
<div class="6u overlay">
            <a href="astronomy.html" class="image full l">
            <img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" title="Astronomy Nights Branding UI/UX" alt="Astronomy Nights Branding UI/UX" />
            <div class="after">Astronomy Nights<br/><span style="font-size:0.5em; font-style:italic; letter-spacing:1px;">Branding, UI/UX</span></div></a>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
 .overlay {
     position: relative;    }


 .overlay .after {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: none;
     color: #000000;    font-size:1.5em;    font-weight:400;    letter-spacing:-1px;    padding-top:3em; }

 .overlay:hover{    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;   -o-transition: all 0.6s
 ease-in-out;   -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;   transition: all
 0.6s ease-in-out;          
        }

 .overlay:hover .after {        
     display: block;
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);    
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `visibility: hidden` instead of `disply:none`and the transition must be in .after not overlay

```
.overlay {
  position: relative;
}
.overlay .after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity:0;
  color: #000000;
  font-size:1.5em;
  font-weight:400;
  letter-spacing:-1px;
  padding-top:3em;
}

.overlay:hover .after {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:1;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/850hhcqd/

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: How come the text doesn't fade in with the background? How do I accomplish that?

Comment: add opacity:0 to the div.after and opacity:1 on hover . see demo here https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/850hhcqd/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start off with, CSS3 transitions can't animate a `display: none` property. If you want the overlay to fade in, I'd use the CSS `opacity` property. Set `opacity: 0;` on the `.overlay .after` first, then in the `.overlay:hover .after` set the opacity to 1. That'll let the overlay animate in and out without hiding it immediately like `display: none` would do.

Here's your CSS (formatted and edited to work). The overlay element is the only thing that changes opacity, and I moved stuff around to make more sense.

Demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMBJML

```
.overlay {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay:hover {   
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay .after { 
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  color: #000000; 
  font-size:1.5em; 
  font-weight:400; 
  letter-spacing:-1px; 
  padding-top:3em;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out; 
}

.overlay:hover .after {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9); 
}
```

Comment: this works too, thank you!